# Regex to match next line in xml input

Tags: regex, xml

I have to write a regular expression to match xml data as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xml conditionname="condition" table="tablename">
    <item endquery="false" field="fieldname" goto="false" newquery="false" operator="=" or="false" value="Data"/>
```

I have written the regex, `(conditionname="condition".*)\n*.*` to match next line , when i am giving `\n` , its not taking, its matching till `tablename">`, i have to match till end of input data.

Please help me out to match next line of data.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xml conditionname="condition" table="tablename">
<item endquery="false" field="fieldname" goto="false" newquery="false" operator="=" or="false" value="Data"/>

Comment: Why do people insist on using Regex in places where it is much easy to use other methods?  XML techniques are much easier to use than regex in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `.` does not match an end-of-line (`\n`).

You can either use a flag to switch on the *DOTALL* mode - the flag here being the `(?s)` at the beginning of the regular expression:

```
(?s)(conditionname="condition").*
```

or explicitely match end of lines:

```
(conditionname="condition")(\n|.)*
```

Both will match until the end of your string.

Comment: the first regex is the one, which i wanted. It works for me . Thanks